# Partial JSON transfer

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I currently have an API in PHP that transfers JSON data. It is then read by Javascript webpage and the data is processed. However, sometimes the data set can be quite large, that will both tax the user's internet and their PC to process the data. I would like to send the count of the results with the data, that can be read before it has finished downloading.

I succeeded just fine putting the count in the headers, however I was told that making custom headers is a huge no no.

Another way I was able to do it is set a SESSION variable, then have a second request to another PHP file that gets the value of the SESSION. However, it can sometimes take a while for the second request to go through and the count is displayed quite late.

Is it possible, without using headers, to send information about the data to be processed before sending the data, and be read by Javascript? Here is my current code:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = sizeof($results);

$final_string = json_encode($results);
$size = mb_strlen($final_string, '8bit');

header('Content-Length: '.$size);
header('Content-Range: 0'); // Content-Length header is dropped unless this is set.

echo $final_string;
```

Comment: Use limit queries and set up a pagination system so you send meta data of total records available , current limit offset, next limit offset and array of current records. Then when user selects `loadMore` or whatever process ... send offset info back so you know where to start next query

Comment: JSON would look something like  `{"total":3456, "current_start": 200, "next_start":300, docs:[/* current rows*/]}`

Comment: Define "quite large"...

Comment: Quite large = A few megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can read part of the transmission using XHR event listeners. Then I can attach the count to beginning of the transmission, so that I read that first with a regex match.

### PHP

```
$return_data = [
    "count" => sizeof($results),
    "results" => $results,
  ];

$final_string = json_encode($return_data);

header('Content-Length: '.mb_strlen($final_string, '8bit'));
header('Content-Range: 0'); // Content-Length header is dropped unless this is set.
echo $final_string;
```

### PHP Output

```
{"count":104,"results":[ {"id":"28078", ...
```

### Javascript

```
function xhrLoadingCall() {

    let xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    // Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        setDownloadProgressAmount(evt);
    }, false);


    return xhr;
}


function setDownloadProgressAmount(event){

    if(resultsCount === null){
        let partialData = event.currentTarget.response;
        let regexMatch = partialData.match(/"count"\s*:\s*(\d+)/);
        if(regexMatch !== null)
        {
            resultsCount = parseInt(regexMatch[1]);
            // do something with result
        }
    }
}

$.ajax({
    xhr : xhrLoadingCall,
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Whats wrong with sending a custom header ?

IMO there is nothing wrong with that.
If you dont want to use custom header, you can have a seperate call that will return the length of the data.

Comment: I was told the reason behind it is because it is not standard practice, and future people coming across your code would be confused. And if future devs want to use the API for their programs, it would be a headache.

Comment: _"would be confused"_ _"it would be a headache"_ LOL that's just nonsense.